# jQuery .show() a div with a specific value attribute

Tags: jquery

I am hiding divs until a specific amount of time has passed, at which I am attempting to tell jQuery to show a specific div with the corresponding time.

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item" value="00:15">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" value="00:30">
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" value="01:00">
        <p>Even more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.content').children().hide();

// some timer function returning timeElapsed

var myTime = '01:00';
if (timeElapsed == myTime) {
  $('.item').attr('value', myTime).show();
}
```

What's happening is all the `.item` divs are showing when the if statement is triggered, instead of the one specified by `var myTime`. What needs to be changed?

Comment: i don't see where have you defined `timeElasped` in your code..?? can u post that

Comment: timeElapsed would be returned by the timer function. I edited the JS comment to clarify that.

Comment: You're giving every `.item` a `value` of `myTime` and then `.show()`ing them all.  You want to use `$(".class[attr=val]")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
if (timeElapsed == myTime) {
    $('.item[value='+myTime+']').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (timeElapsed === myTime) {
  $('.item[value="' + myTime + '"]').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What this line is doing `$('.item').attr('value', myTime).show();` is grabbing all `item` elements setting the `attr` with `myTime` on all `.item` elements and triggering show.

If you need an better selector, namely [`attribute equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`$('.item[value="' + myTime + '"]')`

Another way to do it that doesn't result in querying the dom again would be setting up the timers in a simple `each()` loop.

You should be using `data-*` attributes might work better for you along with jQuery.

Also doing it in total seconds will make working with the value a bit easier as well.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item" data-seconds="15">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-seconds="30">
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-seconds="60">
        <p>Even more text</p>
    </div>
</div>

$("div.item").hide().each(function(index, item){
    var $item = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
      $item.show();
    }, $item.data("seconds") * 100);
});
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/b23uE/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (timeElapsed == myTime) {
    $('.item[value=' + myTime + ']').show();
}
```

or

```
if (timeElapsed == myTime) {
    $('.item').filter('[value=' + myTime + ']').show();
}
```

From the looks of it, you don't need the `if` statement either.